# How do I close the button which is open before the next one is being opend in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, fadein

I got two divs which work as buttons but when I have the first one activated and I click on the other one the first opend div doesnt close itself thus they overlapp so you have to manually close those and this is really impractical.
Here are the functions:

```
$(function() {
    $('#profileButtonImg img').click(function() {
      $("#myProfileMain").stop(true).fadeToggle(250);
    });
});
$(function() {
    $('#optionsButtonImg').click(function() {
      $("#myOptionsMain").stop(true).fadeToggle(250);
    });
});
```

And here are the buttons which are clicked to open the divs:

```
<img id="profileButtonImg" src="pic1.jpg" /></div>
<div id="optionsButtonImg"></div>
```

Here are the divs which are being blended in:

```
<div id="myProfileMain" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="myOptionsMain" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Comment: Your posted selector `'#profileButtonImg img'` doesn't match anything regarding your posted HTML markup

Comment: `$('#profileButtonImg img')` should be `$('#profileButtonImg')`

Comment: I know and I used that before but it worked again like this :/ Really dont know why :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many better ways to do this than my answer below:

```
$(function() {
    $('#profileButtonImg').click(function() {
      $("#myProfileMain").stop(true).fadeToggle(250);
      $("#myOptionsMain").stop(true).fadeOut(250);
    });
});
$(function() {
    $('#optionsButtonImg').click(function() {
      $("#myOptionsMain").stop(true).fadeToggle(250);
      $("#myProfileMain").stop(true).fadeOut(250);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is only working when i pressed #profileButtonImg first and then try opening #optionsButtonImg but not the other way around :( @sajan

Comment: check this fiddle and let me know what changes you want https://jsfiddle.net/y2ubt270/

Comment: Weird, I copied this and now it works :D must have been an error in my tags or something which I didn't catch :O Thanks!! @sajan

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
('#profileButtonImg img').click(
```

to this

```
('#profileButtonImg').click(
```

The first line implies that the trigger is an img within a div with Id profileButtonImg. But in fact the img itself has that Id